# How to send trigger function in injected_scripts in devtools

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, content-script

I have a working extension, but it the dev tool works once only, during initialization, which in manifest I have a content_script defined and that content_script injects a injected_script which relays a series of events

```
window.postMessage({ eventName: window.appName, ... [other details] })

and thru injected -> content -> background -> devtools, it gets to devtools.
```

But what if I want to re-run this injected script, say when I click a button on devtool panel, and what if I want to give some parameters for the data I expect to get back

e.g.

```
// devtools.js
sendToInjectedScript({params: ['appName', 'location']})

// injectedScript.js
// accepts params
window.postMessage({message: params.map((p) => window[p]})
```

how would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run code in the inspected window using [chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_inspectedWindow#method-eval) or with [chrome.tabs.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript). In your Dev Tools panel you can have a button that calls a function to execute a function call in the inspected window. I found a couple of (untested) methods for achieving this, but I'm not totally sure which is more appropriate.

### Method 1: Using `chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval`

**Dev Tools Page:**

```
function sendToInjectedScript(params) {
    chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval('sendWindowParamData(' + message.params + '); + ');
}

sendToInjectedScript({params: ['appName', 'location']});
```

**Injected Script:**

```
function sendWindowParamData(params) {
   window.postMessage({message: params.map((p) => window[p]});
}
```

**Manifest:**

```
"permissions": [
  "tabs"
],
```

### Method 2: Using `chrome.tabs.executeScript`

**Dev Tools Page:**

```
// Create a connection to the background page
var backgroundPageConnection = chrome.runtime.connect({
    name: "devtools-page"
});

backgroundPageConnection.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
    // Handle responses from the background page, if any
});

function sendToInjectedScript(params) {
    // Relay the tab ID to the background page
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        tabId: chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.tabId,
        params: params
    });
}

sendToInjectedScript({params: ['appName', 'location']});
```

**Background Page:**

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(devToolsConnection) {
    // assign the listener function to a variable so we can remove it later
    var devToolsListener = function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
        // Inject a content script into the identified tab        
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(message.tabId, {
            code: 'sendWindowParamData(' + message.params + ');'
        });
    }
    // add the listener
    devToolsConnection.onMessage.addListener(devToolsListener);

    devToolsConnection.onDisconnect.addListener(function() {
         devToolsConnection.onMessage.removeListener(devToolsListener);
    });
}
```

**Injected Script:**

```
function sendWindowParamData(params) {
   window.postMessage({message: params.map((p) => window[p]});
}
```

**Manifest:**

```
"permissions": [
  "tabs"
],
```

I haven't played around with these yet, so this is just some guesswork from looking at the API.

Comment: chrome.tabs is only accessible in background.js

Comment: @user2167582 I updated my answer. I've not really played with an extension yet unfortunately, so haven't been able to test this. I hope it is of some use.